# redirect back to website after cancelled stripe subscription

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, stripe-payments

I have an app where I basically want to say, when the user cancels their subscription from the stripe page, then redirect them back to the login page / register page on my app! I cannot find a solution for this for the life of me. I cannot seem to find a place to do it in the Stripe Dashboard, and I am using the firebase connection with stripe, so it is all stored in there, but even in there, there is no row that shows a cancellation redirect url... my code is here:

```
 export async function goToBilliingPortal(){
  const functionRef = app
  .functions('us-central1')
  .httpsCallable('ext-firestore-stripe-subscriptions-createPortalLink');
  const {data} = await functionRef({returnUrl : window.location.origin});
  window.location.assign(data.url);
};
```

I'm wondering if I can add a field that says like `cancel_url` in here?

Answer (score 3):

You can [configure the **Default redirect link** in your Stripe Dashboard](https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/settings/billing/portal):

> Choose where to redirect customers after they manage their account.

This can also be [controlled via the API with the `return_url` property on the Portal Session](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customer_portal/sessions/create#create_portal_session-return_url) if you need more granular control.

Comment: the default redirect link is only when the user hits the 'back' button from the stripe dashboard, but I need it to actually head back to the website when they hit the CANCEL button... I took a look and couldn't find anything for that.

Comment: To my knowledge there's no way to configure a redirect for that specific condition, the only thing you can specify is the return URL.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is from a while ago, but leaving a comment for others to to find.  Not JS related, but I ran into a similar issue wanting a real redirect after a session portal was completed by a user rather than having to click on the return to url.

You can perform a redirect from the billing portal by passing the needed params for the `['flow_data']['after_completion']` hash:

Example in ruby

```
def self.cancel_portal_session(customer, subscription)
  Stripe.api_key = STRIPE_SECRET
  Stripe::BillingPortal::Session.create(
    {
      customer: customer, return_url: "#{BASE_URL}/billing-details", 
      configuration: CANCEL_CONFIG,
      flow_data: {
        type: 'subscription_cancel',
        subscription_cancel: { subscription: subscription },
        after_completion: {
          type: 'redirect',
            redirect: {
              return_url: "#{BASE_URL}/process-cancellation?subscription_id=#{subscription}"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    )
end
```

[Stipe docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customer_portal/sessions/create#create_portal_session-flow_data-after_completion-type)